# combine multiple rows in excel document having only one column value different to single row showing different values as different column

Tags: sql, excel

i have an excel sheet in which my data table contains data as shown below

```
   name       job     salary
   sumit    carpenter  1000
   sumit    teacher    1000
   sumit    doctor     1000
```

table is as shown above i want to represent data like this

```
name       job1    job2      job3     salary
sumit    carp..  teacher   doctor   1000
```

is there any function to do this i want to convert this data to sql or is there any sql query that can perform the above specified task

Comment: Are all the possible job names known beforehand, or does the new table need to be created dynamically?

Comment: Data that i have is very large this was just to demonstrate my problem  and yes all jobs are specified but consider this also if  a person named john its not necessary that he would also have 3 jobs it can have 2 jobs then the job 3 must be blank

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Oracle** database then you can you **PIVOT** clause to active this kind of record. let's consider your table name is **EMP**.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT * FROM EMP
  ) PIVOT (MAX (JOB) FOR JOB IN ('carpenter' AS "JOB1",'teacher' AS "JOB2",'doctor' AS "JOB3"));
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6585/4)**

Comment: how do i do it for large amount of data and also not necessarily all names got 3 jobs can have more or less...

Comment: In the previous comment you said that all jobs are specified.Please first find out all the jobs then you can use all the jobs in pivot clause. let's consider there are six kind of job (pilot,teacher,engineer,architect,doctor,carpenter) then you can use those jobs in pivot clause like this `PIVOT (MAX (JOB) FOR JOB IN ('carpenter' AS "JOB1", 'teacher' AS "JOB2", 'doctor' AS "JOB3", 'pilot' AS "JOB4", 'architect' AS "JOB5", 'engineer' AS "JOB6")` if any user has four jobs then it will return 4 jobs and other 2 null, if any user has 3 jobs then it will return 3 jobs and 3 null